# CSS Div&Classes Styling Priorities

Tags: html, css

I've been learning some HTML & CSS recently, and I had a question on how CSS style priorities work and also which style gets applied when we have conflict situations.

So let's look at the following code:

```css
.container {
  color: green;
}
.things {
  color: blue;
}
p#item {
  color: yellow;
}
#item {
  color: orange;
}
.things .container {
  color: brown;
}
p.things {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container things">
  <p>A</p>
  <p id="item">B</p>
  <div class="container">C</div>
  <p class="things">D</p>
</div>
```

Now based on the answer key provided to us, the colors of the different elements are: A-Blue, B-Yellow, C-Brown and D-Red. Now B & D, I find pretty easy to understand. However, I don't understand how A & C got the colors that they did. I guess essentially I'm struggling to see why A & C aren't the same color. Could someone explain how it all works?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know CSS specificity?

Comment: Presumably you meant `.container` not just `container`?

Comment: Yes Indeed, that was a typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets get into styles one by one,

Here you color everything to green, by default

```
 .container {
        color: green;

    }
```

Now you overwrite(only those elements which have both classes `container` and `things`) to blue,

```
.things {
    color: blue;

}
```

(in your case it is the parent div, so everything will now have a blue color )So here everything including `A` and `C` becomes Blue

So here ,

```
A-> Blue
B-> Blue
C-> Blue
D-> Blue
```

Now you color container which is inside the things(so only C satisfies this condition) to brows, thus c is brown.
   .things .container {
        color: brown;

```
}
```

So here ,

```
A-> Blue
B-> Blue
C-> brown
D-> Blue
```

Also,

```
p#item{
    color: yellow;

}
#item {
    color: orange;

},
```

here though `#item` is colored orange at last, still p#item has the most [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so the color for `B` becomes yellow

So it becomes,

```
A-> Blue
B-> yellow
C-> brown
D-> Blue
```

And finally you give this style,

```
p.things {
    color: red;

}
```

Only D satisfies this rule, so `D` becomes red

So final result is,

```
A-> Blue
B-> yellow
C-> brown
D-> red
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS is a Cascading Style Sheet, which means the styles are applied from the top to the bottom.  The first `<div class='container things'>` first gets the `color:green` style from the container class, but then that is overwritten by the `color:blue` by the things class. Now since the first `<p>` tag inside that div is not being targeted by any CSS, it inherits the color from its parent, which is blue, hence A becomes blue.

As for C, the lowest selector that targets C is the `.things .container` selector, which targets elements with the container class that are inside an element with a things class, resulting in C being brown.

Also check out the other answers for information about specificity.

Answer (score 2):

`CSS` styles are applied from top to bottom and if you applied multiple classes on 1 element like your `.container` class first applies the `color:green` which is overwritten by the the `color:blue` from the `.things` class.

So first you applied the `.container` class that initially applies the `color:green` on the all the DOM elements. Then `.things` class overwrites the style by applying 'color:blue' which shows the A in blue color. Then B gots the style from `.item` class and changes its `color:blue` to `color:yellow` and then you applied `.container` class again on the `<div>` which contains C which overwrites the `color:blue` to `color:green` again. And at the end you applied the `.things` class to your `<p>` which overwrites the `color:blue` by `color:blue`.

But if you are confused in the order of CSS classes, You can overwrite the style by forcefully applying the color you want by using `!important` at the end of your styles.

like in your container class :

```
.container {
    color: green !important;
}
```

it will apply the same color on A and C whatever the classes order or styles, it always applies the green color to the element which contains multiple classes including `.container`. and other classes.

**[Working Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/4Lkuhm77/)**

**Edit:**

If you want the style to not be overwritten by any class and always applies the style(means all the styles including color) that you have define with the `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS specificity said that stronger always win. 
See his link to calculate what ruke is stronger than others: [css-specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

In fact, **Id** is stronger than **class** that is stronger than **elements**.
Style elements (**inline**) is stronger that **Id**, and there is again strongest than inlin: the **!important;** so

!important; > inline > Id > class > elements. You can combine multiple id, class or elements to make difference.

If some rules are exactly equals, the latest take the advantage.

See this funny picture to understand it:

[image: learn with father and troopers]

Answer (score 0):

in simple word, the more specific one gets selected so for example if you add these lines of code:

```
 <p class="things" id="ye">D</p>
 p.things#ye{color:black}
```

the D is gonna be black because you had more selectors.